# Find ALL the paths in a binary tree equal to a sum

Tags: algorithm, recursion, optimization, time-complexity, binary-tree

For example, given the following binary tree:

[2,3,5,4,8,6,-2,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,2] and sum = 7

```
                        2
                      /     \
                    3         5
                 /     \    /   \
                4       8  6     -2
                                  \
                                   2
```

Print : [3,4] , [2,5] , [2,5,-2,2]

I could come up with a n^2 solution, but is there a better solution to it? Maybe with a some extra memory, like using a stack or hashtable.

I've spent 4 hours trying to come up with some solution, but all the solution becomes too ugly or chaotic.

My n^2 solution is relatively simple:
1) Have one method i.e. helper which recursively calls itself till all the leafs. When it finds a path with the sum, add it to the result. (This is will take O(n))
2)Call this method for every node in the tree ( O(n) * O(n) = O(n^2))

My simple solution

```
//TreeNode structure
public class TreeNode {
     int val;
     public TreeNode left;
     public TreeNode right;
    TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
     }

//Solution class
public class Solution {

    public List<List<Integer>> pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {

        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        if (root == null) return result;
        Queue<TreeNode> q = new LinkedList<>();

        q.offer(root);


        while ( !q.isEmpty())
        {
            TreeNode top = q.poll();
            helper(top,sum,temp,result);

            if (top.left != null) q.offer(top.left);
            if (top.right != null) q.offer(top.right);
        }


        return result;
    }

    public void helper(TreeNode root, int sum, List<Integer> temp, List<List<Integer>> result)
    {


    if (root == null) return;
    temp.add(root.val) ;
    if (root.val == sum) 
    {

        result.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
    }

    helper(root.left,sum-root.val, temp, result );
    helper(root.right, sum-root.val, temp, result);

    temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);

    }

    }

//Execution class
public class treeApp {

public static void main(String args[])
{    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(2);
    root.left = new TreeNode(3);
    root.right = new TreeNode(5);

    root.left.left = new TreeNode(4);
    root.left.right = new TreeNode(8);

    root.right.left = new TreeNode(6);
    root.right.right = new TreeNode(-2);

    root.right.right.right = new TreeNode(2);

    Solution sol = new Solution();

    List<List<Integer>> result ;
    result = sol.pathSum(root, 7);

    for (List l : result)
    {
        System.out.println(l.toString());
    }

}
//Prints:
[2, 5]
[2, 5, -2, 2]
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the tree in any convenient fashion (breadth-first or depth-first), but include the path to this node.

At each node, check all of the path sums that end at this node; if any equal the target value, add those paths to the solution (passed back as the functional result).

Then recur: add the current node to the path and call on each child.

Is this clear enough?  I think this solves the problem in less time.  The traversal is O(N) to reach all the nodes.  At each node, you walk through the path, which is of length .  If you have a balanced binary tree, the depth is O(log2[N]).